# My USB boots on a laptop, but not on mine

Tags: boot, usb, laptop, bios

I have a recently bought a laptop. ASUS VivoBook 14 with a i5 11th gen.

I wanted to do some tests with wifislax, I used rufus to create the boot device, when I select the USB bootable disk I see a black screen with an underscore. Not blinking.

When I use the same USB on another Laptop, an old Toshiba, it boots perfectly.

- Secure boot is disabled
- The BIOS recognize it perfectly
- I tried it with all the USB ports
- Rufus formats it on FAT32
- I tried format it on NTFS but Rufus does not allow it.
- Changed the boot order to USB first
- Tested the USB with a original Windows 10 ISO

What other things can I do?

Comment: try contacting asus support.

Answer (score 1):

Please see:

[Boot from USB](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-boot-from-usb-drive-within-windows)

In addition to disabling Secure Boot, you need to go into BIOS and change the Boot Order to boot from USB first.

This will get around Fast Start which quickly boots to the main disk.

Comment: Just changed the order boot. Now the USB is booting first. I see the same when the USB boots, a black screen with a non-blinking white underscore. I'm starting to think that is something related to BIOS

Comment: Make sure the USB has proper setup to boot a modern machine. Try on another machine.

Comment: I tested it on a Toshiba Satellite L635. It's an old machine, and the USB boots perfectly there, without any problem

Comment: Try a more modern USB boot software so as to work with Windows 11 / 10. Indeed, make a new key altogether.

Comment: Which one would you recommend me? Aside from using rufus, I also used [Universal USB Installer](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/). And I had the same result

Comment: Try a Windows ISO.  Make it bootable on a new key with Rufus

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141488/discussion-between-thestuckboy-and-john).

Comment: I dislike chat .   Try what I said and post back.  The issue is your bootable media, not the method as that I have covered.

Comment: When I bought the laptop it came without OS, I booted an original Windows 10 ISO from [Microsoft official page](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/software-download/windows10). I used the same USB and it worked fine, the only issue is that I had to add some drivers from [ASUS FAQ](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1044458/) to the root of the USB to make the disks partitions detectable.

Comment: Your boot software now will have to take partitions into account if different from the standard 3

Comment: What instructions can I take from here? What booting software for the USB do you recommend me?

Comment: I just use standard Windows software when starting with a USB.

Comment: I tried booting from the Advanced Startup Options of Windows 10 reading the page you provided me... I still have the black screen

Comment: Try a simple Windows USB and see it that works. It certainly should.

Comment: I did what you just said and it certainly worked well

Comment: I showed you what to do so you may wish to consider marking my answer here.

Comment: I still have the problem, the machine doesn't boot the wifislax

Comment: What you are trying to do may not be compatible with Windows 11.

Comment: I'm not understanding. Is there something am I missing? Why my laptop isn't able to boot a wifislax live iso, but an old laptop is able to?

Comment: If is likely the app is not compatible with Windows 11  as I noted earlier.